# How to fix broken icons in elementary os?

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel

[image: Broken application search button]

[image: Broken Back anad next button in file-manager]

Actually, don't have any idea how these icons were broken. Just after restarting my pc I found all these broken icons. Anyone know how to solve this issue [not a critical problem I must say, just bugging me] and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a broken icon set. This could be caused by a wrong translation / language pack and / or changed theme.

You can try to set the Language and Region back to default (English) or try to reinstall the desktop.

Unfortunately I do not have a elementary OS running right now, but I think it can be done with

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

Comment: I have already tried this command but nothing changed; 
It just said "elementary-desktop is already the newest version (1.466+r530~daily~ubuntu5.0.1)"

Comment: Also tried 
sudo apt-get purge elementary-desktop

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop

and 

sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop

Comment: Which version of elementary OS are you using and which theme or desktop?

Comment: I'm using elementary os 5.0 juno with elementary-desktop setup latest ( GTK+ 3.22.30 )

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed SVG icons directory to see if they've been removed?
Location:

- /usr/share/icons/elementary/actions/symbolic/*

The five icons which you have highlighted are:

- Next Icon:

  - go-next-symbolic-rtl.svg
  - go-next-symbolic.svg
- Previous Icon:

  - go-previous-symbolic-rtl.svg
  - go-previous-symbolic.svg
- View Column:

  - view-column-symbolic.svg
- View Grid:

  - view-grid-symbolic.svg
- View List:

  - view-list-symbolic.svg

Try creating the View Column SVG file with:

```
<svg height='16' width='16' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
  <g color='#bebebe' transform='translate(-853 -57)'>
    <path d='M854 60.5v9s0 .5.5.5h12s.5 0 .5-.5v-9c0-.5-.5-.5-.5-.5h-12s-.5 0-.5.5zm1 .5h3v8h-3zm4 0h3v8h-3zm4 0h3v8h-3z' fill='#666' overflow='visible' style='marker:none'/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

### Then reload file explorer.

If that still does not work, try reinstalling the theme through:

- https://itsfoss.com/install-themes-icons-elementary-os-freya/
- http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-themes-or-icons-in-elementary-os (This link also has manual update option)